# 12V Relay Voltage Surge on contact close

Tags: pcb-design, relay, surge-protection

I'm designing a pcb relay circuit to switch on/off power to an inductive load on a 12V line. I'm using an SPST-NO relay ([omron relay](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/G5Q-1A4-DC5/Z3632-ND/1815721)) to switch the circuit open and closed, and I'm having trouble tracking down a high-frequency (~10MHz) +5V voltage spike seen when the switch closes. Any advice on how to clean up the initial power on signal? Oscilloscope attached[image], note the voltage divisions are 5V and the time divisions are at 500ns.

I've tried connecting a TVS diode in parallel with the inductive load with no success. Happy to include a schematic if it's useful. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It could be the contacts bouncing.  Is it a single spike or ringing around 10MHz?  If you tried to include a picture of your scope trace, it didn't work.

Comment: Whoops, edited to add the image of the scope trace. It's a single spike followed by a ring down which stabilizes after a few hundred ns. I hadn't considered by the back emf of a contact bounce. I do have a flyback diode to protect the coil side of the circuit, but it's not clear to me what is needed to protect the contact side.

Comment: Do you have a flyback diode on the load?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relay voltage spikes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/81421/relay-voltage-spikes)

Comment: @winny The problem with this duplicate is that it applies to an AC load, and the main advices given is to switch during zero-crossing, which is not applicable to OP's case. The only applicable advice is, I quote: "... After that it is inductors, resistors and capacitors to construct filters to damp any spikes left". Which certainly is a bit laconic. I'm therefore leaving this question open.

Comment: For clarification, when you say OPEN do you mean not conducting, and when you say CLOSED do you mean conducting? You also do not say where that voltage waveform is being measured. If it is across the switch, then the switch is going from conducting to non-conducting (closed to open).

Answer (score 1):

That looks like standard ringing to me. The inductance and capacitance of the closed circuit is forming a resonator.

I think it's far too fast to be contact bounce.

If you can add resistance in series that will probably fix it, but it's not always feasible.

You can add a diode from the bouncing contact to 12V, so the spike will get clipped.

An RC snubber might also work. That's more complicated, but it's suitable for AC circuits and other unpredictable situations.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add a  MOV(metal oxide varystor) parralell to load
if MOV response is fast enough, It might suppress the over rising

Note : this is only an idea , not tested yet
       but i think it worth to be tried

Answer (score 0):

Try this previous answer.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/81438/166508

*Note: If it works it would be polite to upvote* **his** *answer* **not** *mine.*

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please add at least summarized content to your answer in case the link content changes.